# Factory method: instance does not live long enough

Tags: rust

I'm developing a word generator in Rust. The application consists of two main structs: `Letter` and `Alphabet`.

`Letter` consists of a single character and rules concerning its relationship with other letters.

`Alphabet` contains vectors for vowels and consonants as well as a hashmap with references to the letters in those vectors. This is done so that rules of a letter can be retrieved in O(1) time.

I've created a factory method to read the alphabet from a json string (code below)  but I'm getting an error stating the alphabet instance does not live long enough.

> src/word_generator/alphabet.rs:47:6: 47:14 error: `alphabet` does not
>   live long enough src/word_generator/alphabet.rs:47
>                     alphabet.add_letter(letter);
>
> src/word_generator/alphabet.rs:26:40: 55:3 note: reference must be
>   valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 26:39...
>   src/word_generator/alphabet.rs:26     pub fn from_json(json:
>   &str)->Alphabet{
>
> note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix
>   following statement 3 at 40:37 src/word_generator/alphabet.rs:40      let
>   mut alphabet = Alphabet::new(); src/word_generator/alphabet.rs:41

I understand the error (I hope) but I don't understand why it happens. Why is the instance of `Alphabet`, returned by the function `new()`, borrowed by the variable `alphabet`? Isn't this a move operation?

```rust
pub struct Alphabet<'a>{
    pub vowels: Vec<Letter>,
    pub consonants: Vec<Letter>,
    letters: HashMap<char,&'a Letter>
}

impl<'a> Alphabet<'a>{

    pub fn new()->Alphabet<'a>{

        return Alphabet{
            vowels: Vec::new(),
            consonants: Vec::new(),
            letters: HashMap::new()
        }

    }

    pub fn from_json(json: &str)->Alphabet{

        let data :Json = match Json::from_str(json){
            Ok(_data)=>_data,
            Err(_err)=>panic!("Invalid JSON provided")
        };

        let letters = match data.as_array(){
            Some(_letters)=>_letters,
            None=>panic!("Expected JSON\'s root to be an array but found a different structure.")
        };

        let mut it = letters.iter();

        let mut alphabet = Alphabet::new();

        loop {
            match it.next(){
                Some(x) =>{

                    let letter : Letter= json::decode(&(x.to_string())).unwrap();
                    alphabet.add_letter(letter);

                },
                None => break,
            }
        }

        return alphabet
    }

    fn add_letter(&'a mut self,ref l: Letter){

        match l.letter_type {
            LetterType::Vowel =>{
                self.vowels.push(l.clone());
                self.letters.insert(l.value, &self.vowels.last().unwrap());
            },
            LetterType::Consonant =>{ 
                self.consonants.push(l.clone());
                self.letters.insert(l.value, &self.consonants.last().unwrap());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

P.S.: I'm very new to Rust so any suggestions for improvement to the code are most welcome.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can make your code compile on the [playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/). For example, you don't include what `Letter` or `Json` are, so I am unable to compile it and see the same error that you are getting. Try and make the code [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a smaller example that probably is where you started:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Letter;

struct Alphabet<'a>{
    vowels: Vec<Letter>,
    letters: HashMap<u8, &'a Letter>
}

impl<'a> Alphabet<'a> {
    fn add(&mut self, l: Letter) {
        self.vowels.push(l);
        self.letters.insert(42, &self.vowels.last().unwrap());
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

You then followed the compiler error<sup>**1**</sup>:

```
<anon>:12:46: 12:52 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter 'a in function call due to conflicting requirements
<anon>:12         self.letters.insert(42, &self.vowels.last().unwrap());
                                                       ^~~~~~
<anon>:10:5: 13:6 help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn add(&'a mut self, l: Letter)
```

And continued on, until you got something like this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Letter;

struct Alphabet<'a>{
    vowels: Vec<Letter>,
    letters: HashMap<u8, &'a Letter>
}

impl<'a> Alphabet<'a> {
    fn new() -> Alphabet<'a> {
        Alphabet { vowels: Vec::new(), letters: HashMap::new() }
    }

    fn add(&'a mut self, l: Letter) {
        self.vowels.push(l);
        self.letters.insert(42, &self.vowels.last().unwrap());
    }

    fn parse() -> Alphabet<'a> {
        let mut a = Alphabet::new();
        a.add(Letter);
        a
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

The root problem is that [*you cannot have references to your own members*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423) <sup>**2**</sup>. In the general case, whenever you moved the structure, then the memory location of all the member variables would change, invalidating all the references. This is a bad thing, and Rust would stop you.

The error message you are getting states that there's no possible lifetime that can satisfy what you want — the reference is only valid while the struct doesn't move, but you want to return the struct from the method, *moving it*.

"But wait!" you say, "I have a `Vec` and the contents of the `Vec` are on the heap and won't move!". While technically true (the best kind of true), Rust doesn't track things at that fine-grained of a level.

The general solution here would be to split your structure into two parts. Parse everything from JSON into an `Alphabet` struct with just the `Vec`s. Then pass that struct (likely by reference, maybe by value) to a `AlphabetSoup` struct. That struct can create the `HashMap` all at once and provide a place to cache your values.

<sup>**1**</sup> Newer compilers actually *removed* this suggestion because the false-positive rate was too high and it introduced more confusion than it helped.

<sup>**2**</sup> You actually *can* have references to your own members, but you can then never move the object, which makes it impractical for most cases.

Comment: That's a very thorough explanation. I now understand what exactly the conflicting requirements are. Thanks a lot, especially for going through the trouble of writing a compilable version!